# php - get 2 words by 2 words

Tags: php

I want code to get 2 words by 2 words in php
example :

```
stackoverflow the best site of asking
```

result :

```
2 words : stackoverflow the
2 words : best site
2 words : of asking
```

Comment: Indeed, this is extremely basic stuff? Ever heard of Explode and modulo/multi-step for loops?

Comment: hhhhhh, no, this is way to get word by word : explode(" ", $text)
but i want to get two words by two words

Comment: Use `modulus` and loop through the word by word array and pull out every 2 words. Done and done.

Comment: please give me a code to do that

Answer (score 5):

```
$array_of_words = implode(' ',array_chunk(explode(' ',$text), 2));
print_r($array_of_words);
```

This should give you

> 0=>stackoverflow the 1=>best site 2=>of asking

- [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

  > Chunks an array into size large chunks. The last chunk may contain less than size elements
- [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

  > Join array elements with a glue string

Comment: It is, but without knowing much more about the data source, it's a start from which the poster might find variations to suit the circumstance - feel free to improve the answer.

Comment: @MyStream My bad, that comment was directed at user1194313 assuming everyone is male in gender.

Answer (score 1):

@MyStream's answer is a good one, though another option would be:

```
$str = 'stackoverflow the best site of asking';
preg_match_all('#\S+(\s+\S+)?#', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "stackoverflow the"
  [1]=>
  string(9) "best site"
  [2]=>
  string(9) "of asking"
}
```

Comment: This answer is a better match for the broader range of possibilities and probably will result in fewer changes for more situations.